# Sorting my posts on homepage my specific value in post_meta table

Tags: post-meta, query, order

I'm rather new to Wordpress development, and i have been making my own code to count and display views count on posts.
Now, what i'm trying to do is get the homepage to sort these posts in descending order, ordered by view count.

Is there anyway to replace the query that fetches the posts list with this kind of query ?

```sql
SELECT posts.*, meta.meta_value FROM wp_posts AS posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta
ON posts.ID = meta.post_id 
WHERE posts.post_type = 'post' AND posts.post_status = 'publish' AND meta.meta_key = 'post_views_count'
ORDER BY meta.meta_value DESC;
```

I have been trying to look at the query object in the documentation but i'll admit it's been a struggle to get this to work.

If anyone would be so kind to explain to me how to get there, so i can learn a bit more about this, if you have the time to spare, of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters and if you're not using a static/custom Page (post type `page`) as the homepage, then you can modify the main WordPress query using the [`pre_get_posts` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it to work, it wasn't working because i was changing the query but not The Loop , which was pretty idiotic. All good now !